# How to avoid duplication?

Tags: c#, code-duplication

I'm making a C# application. The application has two classes and multiple methods. While writing the code I stumbled on a problem. I use the same two variables (XList and YList) and one method in both classes. And probably I will need more classes with this code. So I created a duplication problem. Below is a simple version of my code:

```
public class A {
  private testEntities db = new testEntities();
  public List<int> XList = new List<int>();
  public List<int> YList = new List<int>();

  public void GetAllInfo()
  {
    // Get the data from a database and add to a list
    XList = db.Table1.ToList();
    YList = db.Table2.ToList();
  }

  public void DoStuff()
  {
    // Do Stuff with XList and YList
  }
}

public class B {
  private testEntities db = new testEntities();
  public List<int> XList = new List<int>();
  public List<int> YList = new List<int>();

  public void GetAllInfo()
  {
    // Get the data from a database and add to a list (the same as in class A)
    XList = db.Table1.ToList();
    YList = db.Table2.ToList();
  }

  public void DoDifferentStuff()
  {
    // Do ddifferent stuff with XList and YList then in class A
  }
}
```

My question is what is the best way to solve this duplication problem?

After some research I found that I can probably solve this with inheritance or composition. I also read that people choose composition over inheritance. So I wrote the following code to solve the duplication:

```
public class DataPreparation
{
  private testEntities db = new testEntities();
  public List<int> XList = new List<int>();
  public List<int> YList = new List<int>();

  public void GetAllInfo()
  {
    // Get the data from a database and add to a list
    XList = db.Table1.ToList();
    YList = db.Table2.ToList();
  }

  // Implement other methods
}

public class A 
{
  public void MethodName()
  { 
    DataPreparation dataPreparation = new DataPreparation();
    dataPreparation.GetAllInfo();

    UseDataX(dataPreparation.XList);
    UseDataY(dataPreparation.YList);

    // Implementation UseDataX() and UseDataY()
  }
}

public class B 
{
  public void MethodName()
  { 
    DataPreparation dataPreparation = new DataPreparation();
    dataPreparation.GetAllInfo();

    VisualizeDataX(dataPreparation.XList);
    VisualizeDataY(dataPreparation.YList);

    // Implementation VisualizeDataX() and VisualizeDataY()
  }
}
```

As you can see I made a class that handles getting the data from the database. And that the class A and B use the DataPreparation class.
But is this the best way to solve the duplication? Or should I use inheritance or something different?

Comment: start point: how you planning to test your methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should probably only have one method called `DoStuff()` rather than one called `DoStuff()` and another called `DoDifferentStuff()`.

Then you can create an ABC to implement the common code, and have an abstract `DoStuff()` method that is implemented differently in the derived classes:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    private testEntities db = new testEntities();

    public List<int> XList = new List<int>();
    public List<int> YList = new List<int>();

    public void GetAllInfo()
    {
        // Get the data from a database and add to a list (the same as in class A)
        XList = db.Table1.ToList();
        YList = db.Table2.ToList();
    }

    public abstract void DoStuff();
}

public class A: Base
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do Stuff with XList and YList
    }
}

public class B: Base
{
    public override void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do ddifferent stuff with XList and YList then in class A
    }
}
```

(I also think it's a bad idea to have public fields like that - but I'm guessing/hoping that this is just sample code and your real code doesn't have those...)

Other code (except code that creates an `A` or a `B`) would use the object via the `Base` class type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes it's a sample, I want to change the public fields to properties. I have a few questions about this. What's the reason to use inheritance for this? Why not use composition for example? And why do you make an abstract method?

Comment: @BarryStotter The method is abstract because the base class doesn't know how to implement the method. It uses inheritance because that's the only way you can have a virtual method that has different implementations in different derived classes. You can do it with composition by injecting a `DoStuff()` action into the constructor, but for this particular problem I don't think that's better than using inheritance.

Comment: When the implementation of the method in class A was completely different then the method in class B. Would it then be better to not use an abstract method?  Or maybe use composition then?

Comment: @BarryStotter If you want to be able to pass the object to a method that will work with either `class A` or `class B`, then it's generally better to use polymorphism (i.e. inheritance). If you don't want to be able to do that, then it's probably better to use composition. But it's really hard to tell from your example because it's not real code.

Answer (score 2):

One simple option is to use [inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173149.aspx). Make a base class with the shared functionality and the `A` and `B` can inherit from that. For example:

```
public abstract class Base
{
    private testEntities db = new testEntities();
    public List<int> XList = new List<int>();
    public List<int> YList = new List<int>();

    public void GetAllInfo()
    {
        // Get the data from a database and add to a list
        XList = db.Table1.ToList();
        YList = db.Table2.ToList();
    }
}

public class A : Base
{
    public void DoStuff()
    {
        // Do Stuff with XList and YList
    }
}

public class B : Base
{
    public void DoDifferentStuff()
    {
        // Do ddifferent stuff with XList and YList then in class A
    }
}
```